# Angular service's properties aren't setup on creation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test the following angular (4.1) service:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobService {
  private answerSource = new Subject<AnswerWrapper>();
  answer$ = this.answerSource.asObservable(); 

  answer(answer: AnswerWrapper) {
    this.answerSource.next(answer);
  }
```

which I am testing with this unit-test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [JobService]
    });
  });

  it('should emit $answer on answer()', inject([JobService], (service: JobService) => {
    service.answer$.subscribe(val => expect(val).toEqual('test123'));
    service.answer(('test123' as any))
  }));
```

However, I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I really can't see why it would be undefined, as it should be setup on service creation?

Comment: does it work if you don't use `asObservable`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put this line in a constructor

```
answer$ = this.answerSource.asObservable();
```

The answerSource Subject is guaranteed to be initialised before the constructor is run

Comment: I still get the same result?